# Bootstrap : fixed two column layout (740px content / 320px sidebar)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to have one 740px column for the content and one 320px for the sidebar so the container must be 1060px.

[image]

Is there anyway to get this exact grid size in bootstrap ?

I know I can customize there http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ but i dont know the exact numbers for get it.

Comment: Are you still expecting to use Bootstrap's responsive grid features?

Comment: No I dont need it.

Comment: Apologies, I struggle to see a scenario to why this would be used, as fixed widths would be going against Bootstrap's principles on flexible layouts. What do you want this fixed layout for?

Comment: Is not fixed but maximum width, I stil have a flexible a layouts on smaller devices, most websites are like that (facebook, twitter..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't *really* get this "exact grid size in bootstrap" since the Bootstrap grid uses percentage-based columns widths.

The simplest approach is to override the Bootstrap css to **set a specific width** on those columns, which will (of course) result in the columns no longer being responsive. You can still use the responsive grid nested inside the outer columns, and other Bootstrap features.

**2-columns fixed width layout**: http://bootply.com/B9ti0Rjer1

You could optionally use a media query to apply the fixed widths on larger screens only: http://bootply.com/5Kv1z1XCQK

Comment: I dont need the responsive columns so that will do the trick, thank.

Comment: You might be able do it if you set it to be a 53 column grid making the first `col-sm-37` and the second `col-sm-16`. :P  It would take a lot of hacking though for certain...